# Macbook pro mid 2010 GPU panic

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, kernel-panic, gpu

I have one of the faulty mid-2010 MacBooks with a GPU panic problem. I cannot work, while keeping a sane state of mind. My machine is restarting 4-5 times a day.

Here is a example of the log:

```
    Anonymous UUID:       D08A73B5-C99F-5CA4-C4BD-8EBFB414ECB8

Fri Feb 20 01:23:04 2015
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7fa038df7c): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff813aa1d000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.6.22/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff813a71b6b0 : 0xffffff801e022f79 
0xffffff813a71b730 : 0xffffff7fa038df7c 
0xffffff813a71b800 : 0xffffff7f9ebacf1b 
0xffffff813a71b8c0 : 0xffffff7f9ec7650a 
0xffffff813a71b900 : 0xffffff7f9ec7657a 
0xffffff813a71b970 : 0xffffff7f9eef5056 
0xffffff813a71baa0 : 0xffffff7f9ec99ba9 
0xffffff813a71bac0 : 0xffffff7f9ebb396d 
0xffffff813a71bb70 : 0xffffff7f9ebb1478 
0xffffff813a71bd70 : 0xffffff7f9ebb2518 
0xffffff813a71be50 : 0xffffff7f9eb5f2de 
0xffffff813a71beb0 : 0xffffff7fa035f4e6 
0xffffff813a71bf00 : 0xffffff7fa035e20e 
0xffffff813a71bf20 : 0xffffff801e04a20a 
0xffffff813a71bfb0 : 0xffffff801e0d7607 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.6.22)[32862231-50BC-3AF6-87A2-703321AE4F90]@0xffffff7fa037f000->0xffffff7fa0392fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.6.22)[AA46D551-BE0F-33DA-93A3-8F46197BB36F]@0xffffff7fa0377000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f9eab2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f9e6bf000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f9eb0a000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[80899285-3952-30DA-A0F9-357C51E104CF]@0xffffff7fa037a000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[D61B2BB9-4289-318D-9197-5E1E13B1FF32]@0xffffff7f9eb5d000->0xffffff7f9edc5fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f9e6bf000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[D41125CE-69BD-32E7-9B1D-4E83431662DD]@0xffffff7f9eb4d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f9eb0a000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(8.2.4)[B0E6AAA7-E970-3D81-8B43-145D56A3A4AC]@0xffffff7f9edd0000->0xffffff7f9f079fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[D61B2BB9-4289-318D-9197-5E1E13B1FF32]@0xffffff7f9eb5d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f9e6bf000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(100.14.34)[B40DF46A-AA80-39C2-BBC6-DA5DF93509AC]@0xffffff7fa035c000->0xffffff7fa036efff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f9e6bf000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(5.7.1d6)[67BEDCC9-E9AB-3F32-82CE-84729FB82C0A]@0xffffff7f9f463000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[D41125CE-69BD-32E7-9B1D-4E83431662DD]@0xffffff7f9eb4d000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f9eb0a000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.6.22)[91D61DEC-2946-3790-8134-B808C016C4C9]@0xffffff7fa0356000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: iog=0x0

Mac OS version:
13F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9477416E-7BCA-3679-AF97-E1EAAD3DD5A0
Kernel slide:     0x000000001de00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801e000000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 10800555353
last loaded kext at 6238074665: com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0 (addr 0xffffff7fa00c2000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.34
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.2.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    8.2.6
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.4.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.7f3
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.6.22
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Network Service: Svitla, PPP (PPTP), ppp0
Serial ATA Device: INTEL SSDSC2BW120A4, 120,03 GB
Serial ATA Device: ST9500420AS, 500,11 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: what is making it fail ? do you have more lines of that log ?

Comment: It's a full log

Comment: Can you please tell us, how it was solved for you?

Comment: Sadly it wasn't, it's a faulty macbook that not under the warrant, not much i can do here. Saving money for a new machine :)